# A question about the `ArrayResample`

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a confusion with the function of [ArrayResample](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html).This is a illustrative picture in **Details and Options** about the method of "Bin":

[image]

Then I make a example like this:

```
list = {1, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5};
NumberLinePlot[{list, ArrayResample[list, 7, "Bin"]}]
```

[image]

I find the result is very hard to understand

```
{ArrayResample[list, 7, "Bin"], 
 ArrayResample[list, 7, "Bin"] // Differences}
```

> {{1, 9/7, 25/14, 5/2, 45/14, 55/14, 9/2}, {2/7, 1/2, 5/7, 5/7, 5/7, 4/7}}

I think the illustrative picture above just can explain the case when `list = {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5}` but the case when `list = {1, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5}`.Do anybody have a similar opinion?

Comment: By the way, I think `NumberLinePlot` is misleading in any case. Remember, that the values taken as input and given as output are intended to be "y-coordinates", not "x-coordinates", if you will.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I get it.Thank you for such a good summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArrayResample` uses `"Fixed"` `Padding` by default and linear resampling.

So `ArrayResample[list, 7, "Bin"]` is equivalent to

```
padlist = {First@# - {1, 0}}~Join~#~Join~{Last@# + {1, 0}} &@
  Transpose[{Range[Length[list]] - 1/2, list}]
f = Interpolation[padlist, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
f /@ (5/7*(Range[7] - 1/2))
(* {1, 9/7, 25/14, 5/2, 45/14, 55/14, 9/2} *)
```

The figure below is more accurate, than what is in the docs:

[image: resampled]

Black points are original data, red - resampled, as for the "Bin" method with 5 initial points and 7 final points. I modified the initial `list` to get a nicer figure for this.